# Can't convert symbol into integer in rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm writing a simple test checking to see if my controller works, however my tests keep returning

```
3) PasswordResetsController for checking update succeeds 
 Failure/Error: put :update, id: @user.password_reset_token
 TypeError:
   can't convert Symbol into Integer
 # ./app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:23:in `update'
 # ./spec/controllers/password_resets_controller_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in 
 <top (required)>'
```

My tests are as follows...

```
describe PasswordResetsController do

before do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create( :user )
end

context "for checking update succeeds" do
  before do
    @user.password_reset_token = "gB5KGF-3hC4RNHCK5niz9A"
    @user.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    @user.save!(validate: false) 
    put :update, id: @user.password_reset_token
  end


  it { should assign_to(:user) }      
  it { should respond_with(:redirect) }
  it { should redirect_to(signin_path) }
  it { should set_the_flash.to("Password has been reset.")}

end

end
```

Here is a link to my Model https://github.com/thejourneydude/template/blob/master/app/models/user.rb

EDIT: It appears that the problem is originating from my controller. On my local server, I'm returned with

```
TypeError in PasswordResetsController#update

can't convert Symbol into String

Rails.root: /home/jason/ror/template
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:19:in `update'
```

My update action in my controller code is..

```
def update
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at && @user.password_reset_sent_at > 2.hours.ago
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path, flash: { error: "Password reset has expired" }
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to root_url, flash: { success: "Password has been reset." }
  else 
    render :edit, flash: { error: "Hmm.. something went wrong. Let's try that again." }
  end
end
```

What's wrong with my code and how do I fix it?

Comment: Which line is line 19 from the controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you change this line:

```
redirect_to new_password_reset_path, flash[:error] = "Password reset has expired"
```

to:

```
redirect_to new_password_reset_path, flash: { error: "Password reset has expired" }
```

?

My guess is that you should not be able to call `flash[:error] =` in the `redirect_to` since assignment in Ruby returns the value being assigned.  `redirect_to` requires a hash as the second parameter, but it is being called as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the :user parameter, so perhaps this line would give you an error:

```
elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Try doing:

```
before do
  put :update, :id => @user.password_reset_token, :user => valid_user_attributes
end
```

Set valid_user_attributes to the update you want, for example { 'email' => 'new_email@x.x' }

Answer (score 0):

Try change  id: to :id, like this:

```
before do
   put :update, :id => @user.password_reset_token
 end
```

Comment: No, I'm using my own from scratch authentication system. For the password reset I designed it after Ryan Bates Railscast on Password Resetting. His and mine code are almost for verbatim.

Comment: Can you make sure that the second "before" is executed after the first one? Try debugging before the :update action in spec.

Comment: I even tried putting the FactoryGirl creation and subsequent attribute additions to before the :update action and I still have nothing. I wrote a test before it using `get :edit, id: @user.password_reset_token` and the tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using `describe "tests controller"`? If so, you might try changing it to `describe TestsController` or `describe UsersController` (whichever is appropriate) so that RSpec knows what controller is under test.

Otherwise, can you post the full backtrace from the exception message?

Comment: I'm using the appropriate describe MyController syntax. I want to note that after playing around with it for awhile I don't think it's an rspec issue. When actually testing out my app, an error pops on my page. It returns `TypeError in PasswordResetsController#update can't convert Symbol into String`. I posted the controller code in my question since that appears to be the problem.